# Question on the set of $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ so that there exists $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $^tAA=rI_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C_n$ be the set of $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ so that there exists $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $^tAA=rI_n$.

Let $d_n$ be the maximal dimension of a vector subspace of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ included in $C_n$.

How can I calculate $d_1,d_2,d_3$ ?

All the attempts I have tried so far have not succeeded at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for solutions when $r = 1$, you get exactly the set of transformations that preserve distance, i.e., the rotations and reflections. In the case $n = 1$, the set $C_n$ is all matrices; since they're all multiples of $[1]$, $C_n$ is itself a 1-dimensional vectorspaces, so $d_1 = 1$.

For $n = 2$, you have rotations of the form 

`[cos t  -sin t]
[sin t   cos t]`

and the reflections; the factor $r$ just scales these up and down. With this, you can see that $C_n$ contains all linear combinations of the identity and 

`[0 -1]
[1  0]`

so it's at least two dimensional. In fact, it's exactly 2D, so $d_2 = 2$. (Proof that it's not 3D or 4D is left to you. Hint: it doesn't contain the matrix that is all zero except for a 1 in the upper left corner.)

For $n = 3$...I'm guessing $d_3$ is at least 3, since $C_n$ contains the cone on $SO(3)$, which is 3-dimensional, but I don't have a compelling proof or anything just yet.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being obtuse, but why is the sum of two general elements of $SO(3)$ in $C_3$?

Comment: Never, Ted. It's clear that $C_3$ contains $SO(3)$, because $O(3)$ is the set of solutions to the defining equation when $r = 1$. So $C_3$ contains the set of all scalar multiples of things in $SO(3)$, which is what I meant by "the cone on $SO(3)$". And $SO(3)$ is 3-dimensional, in the sense that it's a 3-manifold, *not* in the sense of being a 3D vector space. But that was enough to make me suspect $d_3 \ge 3$. Your question, however, makes me begin to doubt that. Thanks for asking, to give me the chance to clarify.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely doubt it :)